# How to Print BLOB Documents from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html, windows, printing

I am new to PHP and am confused on what I thought would be a basic task. I have a lightbox that displays a list of documents kept as BLOBs in a MySQL database. I have checkboxes next to each document and a print button at the bottom. I simply want the user to select which documents to print and once they hit the print button their print dialog box opens. These are various formats, pdf, doc, xls, etc. My question is how do I send various formats at once to the print dialog without having to show the documents themselves or am I conceptually way off here? Do I need to create another lightbox that shows all the pages we want to print first and then just print everything in that lightbox? Is that even possible with various formats? A little push in the right direction here conceptually or even a good tutorial on php, javascript and printing options would be helpful. All my google searches dealt with printing to the screen. I need to print, print to a printer not display the BLOBs on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use PHP to control people's hardware.

The only way you're going to get a document printed is by using JavaScript to print the current document rendered in the user's browser.  To do this you need:

```
window.print();
```

So if you want to load an external file, you're going to have to output it:

```
print file_get_contents("file.txt");
print '<script type="text/javascript">window.print();</script>';
```